# Transmitting over UART on STM32

Tags: c, stm32

Hello i am using an STM32 as the host mcu for a SI4362 radio.  the radio uses SPI communication to initialize.  although i am stepping through meaning i believe to be receiving correct CTS from the radio it is not working.  i would like to transmit everything i send and receive from the SPI out to a UART terminal for debug.

Here is a sample of what i am sending:

```
   uint8_t RF_POWER_UP[7] = { 0x02, 0x01, 0x01, 0x01, 0xC9, 0xC3, 0x80};
```

I would like to send the bytes over SPI as designated in the datasheet, and then promptly send the output over UART for debugging more easily something like this:

```
    uart_buf_len = sprintf(uart_buf, "\r\nSPI Test\r\n");
    HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart1, (uint8_t*) uart_buf, uart_buf_len, 100)

    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(SDN_GPIO_Port, SDN_Pin, GPIO_PIN_RESET);
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(SS_GPIO_Port, SS_Pin, GPIO_PIN_RESET);
    HAL_SPI_Transmit(&hspi1, RF_POWER_UP, 7, 50);

    //convert RF_POWER_UP to something the UART can transmit in plain text 

    HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart1, RF_POWER_UP, 7, 50);
    do {
        HAL_SPI_Receive(&hspi1, (uint8_t*) spi_buf, 1, 100);
        
    //convert spi buf to something the UART can transmit in plain text 

        HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart1, (uint8_t*) spi_buf, 1, 100);
    } while (*spi_buf != 0xFF);
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(SS_GPIO_Port, SS_Pin, GPIO_PIN_SET);
```

so i feel that writing a function might make the most sense.  i found a helpful post using memcopy, but it converted the bytes into the equivalent ascii value basically returning the equal result. i am now actively searching the correct and appropriate return value for the needed function as well as propper code inside.  i just wanted to make the edits to the post in the meantime as requested.

thank you

Comment: The RF_POWER_UP command is a binary command. So you are transmitting binary data over UART. What do you expect to get? Since the second, third and fourth byte are the same, and the second, third and fourth character on your output are the same, I looks like your code is working just fine.

Comment: i would like to see identically as typed so i guess i need to use a tostring style fuction.  thank you for your help i guess this means im correctly passing the bytes over SPI as well. i was concerned my array of pointers was not correct.

Comment: You have to be more clear and specific. Also you have to post a [mre].

Comment: Please don't tag `c++` when your code is in `c`.

Comment: "i guess i need to use a tostring style fuction": You probably want to output the binary data in hex format.

Comment: - @hcheung c++ tag removed. -@relent95 i apologize if you felt this was not the minimal, the top section is just the array i created that was included in case i completely botched the syntax and someone noticed while checking the actual code.  where as the code is just my implementation of initialization from the datasheets nothing proprietary to this point.  I will work on making it more specific and smaller in the future.  I thought including more code might assist in explaining what i am trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

I found some helpful tools on this stack overflow that gave me what i needed.  i dont quite understand whats going on with the shifting. if someone would like to bring clarity i would appreciate that.

```
void btox(char *xp, const char *bb, int n) {
    const char xx[] = "0123456789ABCDEF";
    while (--n >= 0)
        xp[n] = xx[(bb[n >> 1] >> ((1 - (n & 1)) << 2)) & 0xF];
}
```

from what i gather i am calling the program with a pointer to the first address of an empty string identified in main using xp and likewise the byte aray using bb.  also passing the size of the array of bytes as sizeof would only pass the size of the address.

xx[] is the array containing defining characters to be used for the byte to string conversion.
so running through a while loop until n-1 >= to zero
and i start to get very lost very fast.

it is working but i don't fully understand the code.

Comment: You have to edit both the question and answer. You should have asked like this, 'How can I convert bytes into a hex string?'. Also if you don't understand that code, you should ask another question. Anyway just iterate the loop evaluating expressions for a specific example input, such as bb[] = {0x12, 0x34, 0x56, 0x78} and n = 4.

Comment: This function converts bytes to hexadecimal in an unnecessarily complicated way. There are easier ways to write this function.